# Select Last Record from LEFT JOIN Subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery, left-join

I'm playing with Subqueries and I need to display the most recent note from a `customers_notes` table in a `LEFT JOIN`.
The query I've attempted is returning an error. 
What am I doing wrong below?

```
SELECT c.*, n.datesubmitted                    
FROM `customers` c 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT datesubmitted FROM `customers_notes` 
            ORDER BY datesubmitted DESC LIMIT 1) AS n           
                    ON (c.customerid = n.customerid)
```

The Error I get is: **#1054 - Unknown column 'n.customerid' in 'on clause'**

Comment: you're not selecting a field called `customerid` in you subquery aliased as `n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're missing `customerid` as a field you are selecting in your subquery - that's why you are getting your error.

Second, even if you add that in, you're not going to get the results you want.

I assume that you have a customer, a customer can have more than one note attached to them, and you want to get the customer details, and all the details of his most recent note.

The general approach to this type of problem is:

Find the `max()` date in a subquery, which would look something like:

```
select customerid, max(datesubmitted)
  from customer_notes
  group by customerid
```

And then join to these results in your outer query

```
select c.*, n.*
  from customers c
    left join customer_notes n
      on c.customer_id = n.customer_id
    left join (
      select customerid, max(datesubmitted)
        from customer_notes
        group by customerid ) nn
      on n.datesubmitted = nn.datesubmitted
```

Answer (score 1):

To use `n.customerid` in `ON` clause you have to `SELECT` it first:

```
SELECT c.*, n.datesubmitted                    
FROM `customers` c 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT datesubmitted, customerid FROM `customers_notes` 
            ORDER BY datesubmitted DESC LIMIT 1) AS n           
                    ON (c.customerid = n.customerid)
```

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the required column with which you are joining.
In left join query column name customerid is missed.

Please refer the below query

```
SELECT c.*, n.datesubmitted                    
FROM `customers` c 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT  customerid,datesubmitted FROM `customers_notes` 
        ORDER BY datesubmitted DESC LIMIT 1) AS n           
                ON (c.customerid = n.customerid)
```